# Does there exist a group $H$ such that $|H/Z(H)| = 6$?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, quotient-group

Question: Does there exist a group $H$ such that $|H/Z(H)| = 6$?

If there were to exist such a group then $H/Z(H) \cong C_6$ or $S_3$. Note that if $H/Z(H) \cong C_6$ then $H$ would be abelian, implying that $H = Z(H)$ and hence $|H/Z(H)| = 1$; contradiction. So we must have $H/Z(H)\cong S_3$ if there is to exist such a group. If we take $H$ to be $S_3$, then $Z(H) = \{e\}$ as if we have the permutation $(a_1 \space a_2 \dots a_k)$ then $(a_1 \space a_2)(a_1 \space a_2 \cdots a_k) = (a_2 \space a_3 \cdots a_k)$ but $(a_1 \space a_2 \cdots a_k)(a_1 \space a_2) = (a_1 \space a_3 \cdots a_k)$. So $|S_3 / Z(S_3)| = \frac{|S_3|}{|Z(S_3)|} = \frac{3!}{1} = 6$ and so we have found such a group.

Is this valid?

Comment: Your proof of $Z(S_3)=1$ needs more details perhaps, but after that everything is clear. Of course $S_3/Z(S_3)\cong S_3$ has then $6$ elements. Your argument before is not correct. If $H/Z(H)$ is abelian, then $H$ need not necessarily be abelian. Take the Heisenberg group $H$ over $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: For a final presentation, the first part can be left out - presenting and verifying the counterexample is enough

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/835835/386889

Comment: Not sure what "so we must have $H/Z(H)|$ if there exists such a group" was supposed to be. It seems to me that it is missing some words or symbols.

Comment: The first part now uses, that if $H/Z(H)$ is *cyclic*, then $H$ is abelian. This is correct. So the sentence should be "So we must have $H/Z(H)\cong S_3$ if there is to exist such a group." This seems to be missing, indeed.

Comment: For a non centerless example, the dihedral group of order $12$, $D_6$, has center of order $2$. See e.g. here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_Dihedral_Group

Comment: More generally, $S_3\times A$ with $A$ abelian and arbitrary is an example.

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarise the comments here, so that the question has an answer.
If the quotient group $H(Z(H)$ has six elements, then it must be isomorphic to either $C_6$ or $S_3$. This is well known, and a short proof can be found here:
[There are only two types of groups of order $6.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541635/there-are-only-two-types-of-groups-of-order-6?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Since $H/Z(H)$ cannot be cyclic, as you have shown correctly (since $H/Z(H)$ cyclic implies that $H$ is abelian), we are left with the case of finding groups $H$ such that ${\rm Inn (H)}\cong H/Z(H)\cong S_3$.

It is clear that $H=S_3$ and $H=D_6$ satisfy $H/Z(H)\cong S_3$, because $Z(S_3)=1$ and $Z(D_6)\cong C_2$. Actually, $D_6\cong C_2\times S_3$, and every direct product $H=A\times S_3$ with $A$ abelian satisfies $H/Z(H)\cong S_3$.

A new example is the [*dicyclic*](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/Dic3.html) group $H=C_3\rtimes C_4$ of order $12$, with $H/Z(H)\cong S_3$.